# Get Operation Context in Apex class

Tags: apex, executioncontext

Is it possible to get the way a method is called in Apex?  In my case, I need to determine how a trigger fires: if its called from a external API (jsForce) or if a user deletes a record through the normal Salesforce UI.

I know all of this can be monitored but I need the context in my Apex Trigger Handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers run at the database layer and hence are agnostic about how invoked. Options to distinguish external API from run of the mill UI operation:

- ExternalAPI uses a specific userName as context user
- ExternalAPI uses a user assigned a specific custom permission